# DNS server cannot get DNSSEC information

Tags: dns, home-networking, network-adapter

I did the [netalyzr](http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/index.html) test which checks some ports and network configs.

The result was strange. It contained a problem with DNSSEC:

> Only some DNS root server instances returned proper DNSSEC information. The working roots are: A, B, C, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M

Do i need to worry because apparently the DNS Server from my ISP is unable to obtain information from all DNS root servers or can i ignore this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, all but one worked, right? I bet d.root-servers.net just had a glitch at the time you tested. Try again.

If it still doesn't work, see if you can reach it with a non-DNSSEC DNS query.

If that doesn't work, then maybe your ISP has a broken route to the University of Maryland, who host the D server. Try hitting other resources at the university.

Comment: So there are only A-M dns root server? I was afraid that i was missing N-Z too. I will check again tomorrow, thanks

Comment: you were right, today it works like a charm.

Comment: There are no N-Z root nameserver names at this time, only A-M.  But it's more complicated than that in reality.  Most reference an anycast address with a cluster of DNS servers behind them.